# WPF Keybindings don't work since Window can't focus eventhough focusable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus, key-bindings

I have a window like this:

```
<Window Background="LightBlue" Title="SHMD Ämneshantering"
    x:Class="SHMD_Edit.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SHMD_Edit"
    xmlns:localViewModels="clr-namespace:SHMD_Edit.ViewModels"
    xmlns:localViews="clr-namespace:SHMD_Edit.Views"
     Height="700" Width="1105" MinHeight="750" MinWidth="1005" Focusable="True" Name="window">...</Window>
```

I'm trying to add keybindings that are usable in the whole application, like this:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+R" Command="{Binding AddSubstanceCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

However, the command won't work unless I put focus on something focusable like an element in one of my listviews. I want the user to be able to run the command anywhere, so I tried adding focus to the window, figuring that anything focused on later will be a child of the window and thus the gesture should propagate to the right destination.

However, I can't get the window focused, as you see I've set it focusable, and when checking in the Immediate Window, I can confirm that it is indeed focusable, but running Focus() on it returns false and focus is not set.

How can I set focus to my window? Any other way of getting globally useable keybindings?

Comment: I made the empty Window and `RelayCommand` works. You need to place your markup here to reproduce the problem. Anyway, why cannot you place any element (Visibility = Collapsed) wherever in `Window` and invoke Focus() method on it programatically?

Comment: You were on to something, I hadn't set the datacontext to the whole window but to the grid it contains, that's why nothing worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented global shortcuts before, I think the piece you're missing is to use `RoutedUICommands`, which will handle routing the command through the visual tree.  If you don't you can get into weird focusing issues like you currently have.  Another key point is using the correct `CommandManager` registration method, you want to use either `CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding` or `CommandManager.RegisterClassInputBinding` and set your type in either case to be `Window` which will obviously make it available to WPF globally.

Here are two of the abstract classes I use to create shortcuts for my applications.

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines the base class for application wide shortcuts.
/// </summary>
public abstract class ApplicationShortcut
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="ICommand"/> to be executed.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract ICommand Command { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="InputGesture"/> defining how the <see cref="ApplicationShortcut.Command"/> is invoked.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract InputGesture Shortcut { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the <see cref="ApplicationShortcut"/> with the application.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract void RegisterShortcut();
}

/// <summary>
/// Base class that defines an <see cref="ICommand"/> that is routed through the element tree and contains a text property.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type that is registered with the command.</typeparam>
public abstract class RoutedUIShortcut<T> : ApplicationShortcut
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The type registered with the command.
    /// </summary>
    protected readonly Type OwnerType = typeof (T);

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="RoutedUICommand"/> to be executed.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract RoutedUICommand RoutedCommand { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="ICommand"/> to be executed.
    /// </summary>
    public override sealed ICommand Command
    {
        get { return RoutedCommand; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the <see cref="ApplicationShortcut"/> with the application.
    /// </summary>
    public override void RegisterShortcut()
    {
        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(OwnerType, new CommandBinding(Command, OnExecuted, OnCanExecute));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the method that will handle the <see cref="CommandBinding.CanExecute"/> routed event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The command target that is invoking the handler.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The event data.</param>
    protected virtual void OnCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the method that will handle the <see cref="CommandBinding.Executed"/> and <see cref="CommandBinding.PreviewExecuted"/> routed events, as well as related attached events.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e">The event data.</param>
    protected abstract void OnExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e);
}
```

Then you just need to instantiate your Shortcut classes when your application is starting and call the `RegisterShortcut()` method.

Comment: Where is it even using the InputGesture?